# StatusBar fullscreen view dismissal error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, statusbar

When I dismiss my Modal View to return to the Navigation Controller View I get this strange behavior with my StatusBar
[image]

I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` in the `ViewDidLoad` for my Modal View and I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];` in my NavController View.

Any ideas on how can I prevent this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are setting the statusbar hidden when you're in the menu, and when it's in the detail view it appears?

Comment: It appears she I "come back" from my FullScreen Modal View, where there's no StatusBar. And it should appear, the problem is that it appears not correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the code to viewDidDisappear method of the modal view controller that you present:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Further explanation: the old view get displayed in the window too late, at the time the old view is redisplayed the status bar still hidden, so the uiview of the old controller will get the full size of the widow (that does not have the statusbar) leading in the 20 px shifting that appear in the upper part of the view

Comment: I put it in the `viewWillDisappear` and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with animation?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:YES];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:YES];
```